# onTouchListener to RecyclerView have disabled its scrolling

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a recyclerView which is scrollable horizontally, When the recyclerView is touched at anywhere a dropdown should happen. I have tried many ways like onclick and did not work. Only thing that worked was onTouchListener, but after implementing that the scrolling is not working.

This is the recyclerView code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_selected_groups"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_select_group"
        android:focusable="true" />
```

And here is the code for onTouchListener used

```
 mRecyclerViewSeletedGroups.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
        when (motionEvent.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                dropdownFlag = !dropdownFlag
                mPresenterImpl.onDropdownClicked(dropdownFlag)
            }
        }
        return@OnTouchListener true
    })
```

So when I tried onclick instead of onTouch it was not working.

I want to implement that onTouch as well as the scrolling should work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Put your onTouch logic in recyclerview item. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your:

```
return@OnTouchListener true
```

If you always return true this means:

> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

If you always consume the event, your scroll will not work. You need to review your logic to return **true** only when you want to.

Comment: bro just gave the return statement to false and it worked, really thanks for your help bro

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)